# Не работает перевод из string в int в Delphi - ошибка "E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'StrToInt'"

Tags: delphi

```
program Project2;

var
  Num1, x: string;
  a: integer;

begin
  Num1 := '1';
  a := StrToInt('1');
  readln(x);
end.
```

Ошибка:

> [dcc32 Error] Project2.dpr(9): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'StrToInt'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы столкнулись с данным сообщением, а в существовании функции уверены, то алгоритм действия такой:

Открыть справку, найди в ней данную функцию.

Например, онлайн справка расположена тут: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt

Ищем в ней раздел `Unit`, и вписываем указанный модуль в `uses`. В данном случае это `System.SysUtils`.

В целях обратной совместимости префикс `System.` допускается не указывать, но лучше всё-таки писать.

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается `StrToInt` не доступен просто так. Он находится в модуле `SysUtils`. Я исправил ошибку добавив:

```
uses SysUtils;
```